# Simple click on labels makes double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, label

I have a label and some functions running while clicking on it.

But when a click event is made, a double click event is done, then my functions run 2 times...

You can see a light example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vgWGT/2/)

HTML:

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"> Click here
</label>
<input type="text" id="test" value="0"/> clicks​​​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('label').click(function(event) {
         $('#test').val(parseInt($('#test').val())+1);
         event.preventdefault();
    });
});​
```

- When we click on the checkbox, the clicks counter is +1 >> Ok
- When we click on the label, the clicks counter is +2 >> Nok

How to solve this problem ?

**Edit**

`preventdefault()` to `preventDefault()` fixed the double click, but now checkbox is not checked anymore...

Comment: `preventDefault` has a capital `"D"` in it.

Comment: Why are you binding click handler to the label? and Why are you enclosing a checkbox inside label?

Comment: @Vega: Putting the checkbox inside the label, makes the label toggle the checkbox without needing the `for` attribute.

Comment: check whether you have any code on checkbox value chage event.

Comment: @Vega enclosing the input inside of the label is standard behavior. The specs approve of this.

Comment: @ Valky: I was so intrigued by the question I forgot to flag this up: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question I've put the code in for you.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder Usualy I paste it, but I was so busy with this problem that I forgot... Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well this is interesting. You're seeing two `click` events, one of them from the checkbox `input`, and the other (of course) from the `label`. And it makes sense: Clicking a `label` is like clicking the checkbox the `label` labels, by design. [Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgWGT/15/) showing what's happening.

So just hook `click` on the checkbox and don't hook it on the label:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox').click(function(event) {
        $('#test').val(parseInt($('#test').val())+1);
    });
});​
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgWGT/16/)

---

And as Rocket said in the question's comments: `preventDefault` has a capital `D` in it, so your code was throwing an exception. But you didn't want `preventDefault` anyway, because you want the checkbox to be checked.

Comment: best answer. preventDefault is not needed.

Comment: @Valky: No worries, great question -- I learned something. Glad this helped,

Answer (score 3):

A simple workaround is to ignore one of the call.. See below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('label').click(function(event) {
        if (event.target.nodeName == 'LABEL') return;
        $('#test').val(parseInt($('#test').val())+1);         
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vgWGT/24/)

Comment: Nice, give you a +1, but T.J. Crowder solution is lighter.

Answer (score 1):

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'preventdefault'

The `d` in `preventdefault` should be capitalized.

Edit: the browser behavior for a checkbox nested in a label is to trigger click on the checkbox when the label is clicked. To solve the original problem, only tie the incrementing click handler to the checkbox.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox').click(function(event) {
         $('#test').val(parseInt($('#test').val())+1);
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vgWGT/28/

Related: http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/javascript_debugging_for_beginners/

Comment: While true, it's not the answer to the question. :-)

Comment: Thanks but the checkbox isn't checked anymore :-(

Comment: @Valky what is the intended behavior?

Comment: @jbabey Intended behavior is to have the checkbox clicked and also the click counter to get incremented correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The preventDefault() will disable the original function.
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:#checkbox').click(function() {
         $('#test').val(parseInt($('#test').val())+1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<label for ="checkbox">Click here</label>
<input type="text" id="test" value="0"/> clicks
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('label').click(function(event) {
    var valor = parseInt($('#test').val());
         $('#test').val(valor+1);
         event.preventdefault();
    });
});
```

It works

Answer (score -2):

Do it like this:

```
<div class="click">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<label>Click here</label>
</div>

<input type="text" id="test" value="0"/> clicks​


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click').click(function(event) {
         $('#test').val(parseInt($('#test').val())+1);
         event.preventdefault();
    });
});
```